# Calculate date difference based on column value on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure with ID, State and Date

```
20130323000004  Final       3/23/2013
20130323000004  Final       3/25/2013
20130323000004  Final       3/26/2013
20130323000004  Needs Review    4/5/2013
20130323000004  Final       4/10/2013
20130323000004  Final       5/1/2013
```

and I would need the result like

```
20130323000004  Final       3/23/2013     1
20130323000004  Final       3/25/2013     2
20130323000004  Final       3/26/2013     3
20130323000004  Needs Review    4/5/2013      1
20130323000004  Final       4/10/2013     1
20130323000004  Final       5/1/2013      21
```

where the last column is the difference between the two records based on the state column.

I tried doing a self join with max and min but not able to get the proper count. Can you please help me on calculating the sum in the SQL?

Thanks

Shankar.

Comment: . . Please explain how the numbers are calculated.  For instance, for the second to last row, what does the "1" mean?  What does the "21" mean in the last row?

Comment: It is the difference of days (date) between the two dates based on the state.

Comment: . . I I would expect to see a date one different from 4/10/2013.  And I see neither 4/09/2013 nor 4/11/2013.  Please fix the example.

Comment: the sample is the data from database - since the state changed during that date the count should starts from 1 again. It is not just dependant on the date - it has to count based on the previous state and the dates

Comment: . . If 3/23 has a value of "1", why does 3/25 have a value of "2"?  These should either be "0" and "2" or "1" and "3", by my reckoning.

Comment: Since 3/23 is the first occurance of the final state and 3/25 and 3/26 are calculated from 3/25 (two dates on the same state). Then the count gets reset as the state changes

Comment: But `26-25 = 1`, not `3`

Comment: It is 26 to 23 on the same state hence 3

Comment: So, if you had a `3/24/2013` as well, it would get a `1`?

Comment: yes. for the purpose of calculation can have it however we want.. but would like to achieve the same result.. essentially based on the state the dates should be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, I'm pretty sure it's what you're looking for

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[State]
  ,[Date]
  ,DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MIN([Date]) FROM [tableName] where [State] = a.[State]), [Date])
FROM [tableName] a
```

Comment: This would not give you 1 for the `4/10/2013` record

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,ET.EffectiveDate,ET2.EffectiveDate),DATEDIFF(DAY,ET.EffectiveDate,GETDATE())) DayDifference,
    ET.EmployeeID,ET.EffectiveDate 
     FROM(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By EmployeeId Order By EffectiveDate) RowNumber,EmployeeID,EffectiveDate 
        FROM  Employee.EmployeeTransfer
     )ET
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By EmployeeId Order By EffectiveDate) RowNumber,EmployeeID,EffectiveDate 
        FROM  Employee.EmployeeTransfer
    ) ET2 ON ET.EmployeeID=ET2.EmployeeID AND ET.RowNumber=ET2.RowNumber-1
    ORDER BY ET.EmployeeID, DayDifference
```